# NLP Produce Collocated Trigrams Dataframe Grouped By Values in A Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, append

I have the following sample data frame.  Let's pretend each letter is actually a word.  So for example, `a = 'ant'` and `b = 'boy'`.

```
id  words
1   [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
1   [h, I, o]
1   
1   [a, b, c]
2   [e, f, g, m, n, q, r, s]
2   [w, j, f]
3   [l, t, m, n, q, s, a]
3   [c, d, e, f, g]
4   
4   [f, g, z]
```

The code to create the above sample dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd 

d = {'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4], 'words': [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'], ['h', 'I', 'o'], '', ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'm', 'n', 'q', 'r', 's'], ['w', 'j', 'f'], ['l', 't', 'm', 'n', 'q', 's', 'a'], ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'], '',  ['f', 'g', 'z']]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I run the following NLP code on it to do the following: Give me a count of various 3-word combinations collocated together from the "words" field.

```
from nltk.collocations import *
from nltk import ngrams
from collections import Counter


trigram_measures = nltk.collocations.BigramAssocMeasures()

finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_documents(df['words'])

finder.nbest(trigram_measures.pmi, 100) 

s = pd.Series(df['words'])

ngram_list = [pair for row in s for pair in ngrams(row, 3)]

counts = Counter(ngram_list).most_common()

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(counts, columns=['gram', 'count'])
```

The sample resulting hypothetical output is as follows (data values are fake):

```
gram                          count 
a, b, c                       13
c, d, e                       9
g, h, i                       6
q, r, s                       1
```

The issue is I want to have the resulting output split by the "id" field.  **My desired sample output is below (data is fake and random)**:

```
id   gram                          count 
1    a, b, c                       13
1    c, d, e                       9
1    g, h, i                       6
1    q, r, s                       1
2    a, b, c                       6
2    w, j, f                       3
3    l, t, m                       4
3    e, f, g                       2
4    f, g, z                       1
```

How do I achieve this?  ... getting results by "id" field?

Comment: Could you add the code for creating the input DataFrame?

Comment: Code to create dataframe has been added ... please see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you could wrap your code in a function and apply it to groups from a group by `id`, something like this:

```
import nltk
import pandas as pd

from nltk.collocations import *
from nltk import ngrams
from collections import Counter

d = {'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4],
     'words': [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'], ['h', 'I', 'o'], '', ['a', 'b', 'c'],
               ['e', 'f', 'g', 'm', 'n', 'q', 'r', 's'], ['w', 'j', 'f'], ['l', 't', 'm', 'n', 'q', 's', 'a'],
               ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'], '', ['f', 'g', 'z']]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


def counts(x):
    trigram_measures = nltk.collocations.BigramAssocMeasures()
    finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_documents(x)
    finder.nbest(trigram_measures.pmi, 100)

    s = pd.Series(x)

    ngram_list = [pair for row in s for pair in ngrams(row, 3)]

    c = Counter(ngram_list).most_common()

    return pd.DataFrame([(x.name, ) + element for element in c], columns=['id', 'gram', 'count'])


output = df.groupby('id', as_index=False).words.apply(counts).reset_index(drop=True)
print(output)
```

**Output**

```
    id       gram  count
0    1  (a, b, c)      2
1    1  (h, I, o)      1
2    1  (b, c, d)      1
3    1  (d, e, f)      1
4    1  (c, d, e)      1
5    1  (e, f, g)      1
6    2  (g, m, n)      1
7    2  (q, r, s)      1
8    2  (m, n, q)      1
9    2  (n, q, r)      1
10   2  (f, g, m)      1
11   2  (w, j, f)      1
12   2  (e, f, g)      1
13   3  (t, m, n)      1
14   3  (q, s, a)      1
15   3  (e, f, g)      1
16   3  (d, e, f)      1
17   3  (m, n, q)      1
18   3  (c, d, e)      1
19   3  (n, q, s)      1
20   3  (l, t, m)      1
21   4  (f, g, z)      1
```

Comment: wow, your solution is awesome; I'm trying to understand what the following line of code is doing conceptually:  return pd.DataFrame([(x.name, ) + element for element in c]

Comment: That actually creates a DataFrame from a list of tuples. In the tuples the first element is the id, that in this case is the same as the group name, and the other elements are the gram and the count.